# port forward in INPUT level

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, ipv6, nat

I want to change the destination port of the ipv6 packet in the INPUT level.

So I tried to use ip6tables with nat in the INPUT level

but seems this command does not work

```
# ip6tables -t nat -I INPUT ! -i br0 -p TCP --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 80
ip6tables v1.2.7a: Unknown arg `--to-ports'
Try `ip6tables -h' or 'ip6tables --help' for more information.
```

I think beside the error returned by iptable, I think that nat is not working in the INPUT level.

So are there a solution to change the destination port of the ipv6 packet in the INPUT level?

I do not want to change it in the PREROUTING level since I do not want change the ipv6 packet that will be forwarded  (not for loacal process)

Comment: If you don't want to change other packets, limit the rules destination IP to your IP.

Answer (score 0):

NAT does not work in the INPUT chain.
From http://www.karlrupp.net/en/computer/nat_tutorial :

> REDIRECT - Redirect packets to local machine
>
> A special case of DNAT is REDIRECT. Packets are redirected to a local
>   port of the router, enabling for example transparent proxying. As for
>   DNAT, REDIRECT acts within the PREROUTING and the OUTPUT chain
>   respectively.

If you want to redirect only packets to your own server, add destination ip limit to the rule (1.2.3.4 is your local IP):

`ip6tables -t nat -I PREROUTING ! -i br0 -p TCP -d 1.2.3.4 --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 80`